# Error while inserting

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sql-insert, ora-00600

```
Oracle version: 11.2.0.1
```

I am trying to insert a row in one of my table. But I get an error. Following is the insert statement.

```
INSERT INTO FURNAC_LOG (TRANSACTIONID,
                        ERRORSTRING,
                        ERRORCODE,
                        STARTTIME,
                        ENDTIME,
                        HOSTNAME,
                        ROUTE,
                        LOTNAME,
                        ENTITYNAME,
                        CONTROLJOBTYPE,
                        ILOOPLOGFILE,
                        TIMESTAMP,
                        DATESTAMP,
                        EQREQFILE,
                        EQRESFILE,
                        ILOOPREQFILE,
                        ILOOPRESFILE,
                        FAILEDBYINCLUDELIST,
                        ERRORPREFIX,
                        EQHOSTNAME,
                        EQDOMAINNAME,
                        EQUSERNAME,
                        PRETOOL,
                        JOBNAME,
                        LAYER)
     VALUES (
               '512-912_20130621182722',
               'StoreEquipmentDataSection(): Object reference not set to an instance of an object.',
               '-1000',
               TO_DATE ('2013.06.21 18:27:22', 'yyyy.mm.dd hh24:mi:ss'),
               TO_DATE ('2013.06.21 18:27:50', 'yyyy.mm.dd hh24:mi:ss'),
               'INFMY10251',
               'c',
               'RU020560',
               '512-912',
               'Metrology',
               '\\172.29.29.186\LatestSourceR2R\R2RServices\R2RServices\Data\error\FURNAC_Metrology\RU020560_2013_06_21_18_27_22_409-22.log',
               SYSDATE,
               TRUNC (SYSDATE),
               '\\172.29.29.186\LatestSourceR2R\R2RServices\R2RServices\Data\error\FURNAC_Metrology\RU020560_2013_06_21_18_27_22_409-22.xml',
               '',
               '',
               '',
               'F',
               '',
               'INFMY10251',
               'CHENNAIODC',
               '299900',
               '',
               '123456',
               'c')
```

Following is the error which I get when I try to execute it.

```
SQL Error: ORA-00603: ORACLE server session terminated by fatal error
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [kqd-objerror$], [U], [0], [96],   [BIN$T0b+1g9lTmqpxZownkRPVg==$0], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
00603. 00000 -  "ORACLE server session terminated by fatal error"
*Cause:    An ORACLE server session is in an unrecoverable state.
*Action:   Login to ORACLE again so a new server session will be created
```

All the other queries work perfectly. It happens only when I try to execute this query.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, internal errors just happen...

Try doing the following:

1) Recreate the table from scratch

2) Mask all table fields with quotes

3) Rewrite insert query. Even a small cosmetic change can help you.

4) Also, you can try to update to 11.2.0.3

Looks like magic? Yup, that's exactly what it is.